# Make navbar stick upon scrolling to position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my website's navigation bar stick to the top of the page after scrolling to it along with the header image.
So far the code I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="C:\Users\Karl\Desktop\New Bistro\menu_assets\styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style>
.header{
 height:70%;
 background-image:url('http://s22.postimg.org/4eags0oep/header.png');
 background-size: cover;
 width:100%;
}
.nav{
 height:8%;
 width:100%;
}
.body{
 height:100%;
 background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/Solna_Brick_wall_Silesian_bond_variation1.jpg');
}
.logo {
 background-image:url('Title.png');
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 height:140px;
 width:554px;
 right:35%;
 position:fixed;  
 z-index:9999 
}
</style>
</head>
<body background="http://htmlgiant.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/A-grey.jpeg" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">

<div class="header">
<a href="#Home"><div class="logo"></div></a>
</div>

<div class="nav">
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li><a href='http://www.132glenbistro.com/'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='http://www.132glenbistro.com/'><span>Menu</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='http://www.132glenbistro.com/'><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='http://www.132glenbistro.com/'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="body">
<div align="center">
<table width="70%" style="height: 200%;" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="height: 100px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
</td></tr></table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My css file is:

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #232323;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
  -o-transition: color .15s;
  transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
  transition: all .3s .1s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 65px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fafafa transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #323232;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 206px;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 190px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #cc2c24;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

I have tried using javascript to do this to no avail. I am new to javascript programming in general any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Too much code. A small isolated sample on jsfiddle.net would help better

Comment: A fixed position element is definitely possible with pure css. Your question's code references local cds paths, so we wouldn't be able to see that styling. Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can further troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Bootstrap provides this feature called "Affix". Even if you only use this aspect I think it would be much more beneficial to use Bootstrap than try to do it yourself. Or you can look at the source to get an idea of how they do it.

Either way without seeing your attempts I don't see how we're supposed to help you.